# Magento 2 - setup:install & setup:upgrade

Tags: magento2, setup-script, command-line, setup-upgrade

I have updated the code in my custom module and run `setup:install` already. Do I still need to run `setup:upgrade`?

Answer (score 3):

when you are installing new extension at that time you need to run a command,

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

if you have already run command and you can change inside a module, you don't need to run upgrade command.

**At that time you have to run upgrade command, when you have changed inside setup folder, for table new entry insert or delete already field from table when upgrade table schema, those time you need to run upgrade command.**

Comment: Not sure about "when you are installing new extension" ... If the shop is in a git repository that I have cloned, there might be some required Magento extensions (with db modifications). Is this also 'new'? I call `setup:install` ... Do I have to call `setup:upgrade`? Or does `setup:install` has already included those extra extensions?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to call `setup:upgrade` if you've installed a new module *or* if you've made changes to the `/setup/` directory of your module. I.e. added a column or changed something in the `UpgradeSchema.php` file.

Answer (score 0):

> Anytime you perform an action that causes the Magento database schema or data to change, you must update them by running the command discussed in this section. A partial list of reasons follows:

1) You upgraded the Magento software using the command line
2) You installed or updated a component using the command line
3) You enabled or disabled a component using the command line

A Magento component can be a module, theme, or language pack; it doesn’t matter whether the component comes from the Magento Marketplace or not,

Please Refer the Link [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-subcommands-db-upgr.html) -> **Upgrade the Magento database schema and data**.